# Custom date sort

Tags: vb.net, sorting, date, alphanumeric

I have a list of date values

> 10/06/2017, 4/20/12, 7/13/12, 08.02.12, 04.05.13, 11.27.12

that needs to be sorted into correct chronological order.

The format from the original data entry was not controlled and therefore is variable. Date seperators, thus far, have shown to be '.' and '/'. The number of digits in each date segment are not consistent.

This list represents a single column of data in a table. The data is read from varying sources and can be put into any structure that will facilitate the sort. The date must sort the entire table.

The data must remain as originally entered so I cannot simply convert the data and be done with it.

Comment: This is a bit vague - is it a list or a table or a datatable?  The dates must actually be strings which is very problematic.  You could create a new field/column/element which is the parsed value and sort by that without changing the real data

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function and overload which will work with either a string as you provided, or a list of strings:

```
Private Function getSortedDates(input As String) As IEnumerable(Of DateTime)
    Return getSortedDates(input.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
End Function

Private Function getSortedDates(input As IEnumerable(Of String)) As IEnumerable(Of DateTime)
    Return input.
        Select(Function(s As String) DateTime.Parse(s.Replace(".", "/"))).
        OrderBy(Function(d) d)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Sub Main()
    ' as a string
    Dim input1 = "10/06/2017, 4/20/12, 7/13/12, 08.02.12, 04.05.13, 11.27.12"
    Dim output1 = getSortedDates(input1)
    ' as an array
    Dim input2 = {"10/06/2017", "4/20/12", "7/13/12", "08.02.12", "04.05.13", "11.27.12"}
    Dim output2 = getSortedDates(input2)
    ' output1 and output2 have the same sorted dates.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a custom Comparer that can be used in sorting

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim dates() As String = {"10/06/2017", "4/20/12", "7/13/12", "08.02.12", "04.05.13", "11.27.12"}

        Array.Sort(dates, New StringDateSorter)

        For Each d In dates
            Console.WriteLine(d)
        Next

    End Sub

End Module

Class StringDateSorter
    Implements IComparer(Of String)

    Public Function Compare(x As String, y As String) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare
        Dim d1 = Date.Parse(x)
        Dim d2 = Date.Parse(y)
        Return Date.Compare(d1, d2)

    End Function
End Class
```